# Butterknife framework, handling included layouts for multiple widget variables

Tags: android, android-layout, butterknife

I have just been introduced to Butterknife framework for field binding.
My problem is that I get the following compilation error while implementing Butterknife in one of my fragments, which works fine while I was using `findViewById()`

> Error:(52, 65) error: Attempt to use @BindView for an already bound ID
>   3454353 on 'tvRFCExt'.
>   (com.org.ui.fragments.SummaryFragment.tvRFCElect)

Fragment

```
@BindView(R.id.tv_rfc)TextView tvRFCExt;
@BindView(R.id.tv_rfc)TextView tvRFCElect;
@BindView(R.id.rt_bar)RatingBar ratingBarExt;
@BindView(R.id.rt_bar)RatingBar ratingBarElect;

onCreateView(){
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false);
}
```

fragment_summary.xml includes the layout which are similar. Both have a Rating bar and a TextView.

```
<include
android:id="@+id/viewRatingExtTyres"
layout="@layout/rating_view"></include>
<!-- rating-->
<include
android:id="@+id/viewRatingElecInter"
layout="@layout/rating_view"></include>
```

The included layout looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"

        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_apperance_small" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_Title"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rt_bar"
            style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:progressTint="@color/colorSubmitBtn"
            android:rating="0"
            android:saveEnabled="false"
            android:stepSize="0" />
</LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.6">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_rfc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/txt_rfc"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_apperance_medium" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_rfc"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/row_color_text"></View>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/txt_no_rting"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_apperance_medium" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Now this has been working fine with the `findViewById()` approach. What changes would I need to do to ensure that Butterknife framework works here.

Comment: try `@BindView(R.id.viewRatingExtTyres) LinearLayout linear;`

Answer (score 0):

try used this code:

```
onCreateView(){
mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_summary, container, false);
ButterKnife.bind(this, mView);}
```